# some issue about the aggregator module. (spring integration)

Tags: spring-integration

I made some aggregator using spring integration.
and If count of requests with same group key is 7, the aggregator has to be released for going to the next channel. 
But, even if the count becomes 7, the aggregator doesn't release. 
the most weird thing is.. sometimes, it worked..

the jdbc-cache-store table, 'int_message_group' 
-> complete is 1 released 0

```
GROUP_KEY   REGION      MARKED      COMPLETE    LAST_RELEASED_SEQUENCE      CREATED_DATE    UPDATED_DATE  
57eba5ba-dfdb-3901-a03d-4324942cdcfe    DEFAULT 0   1   0   2014-11-19 22:37:01.272 2014-11-19 22:41:37.935
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to see your `<aggregator>` configuration and understand what is your groups.

If you use the same `correlationKey` (static) you should use `expire-groups-upon-completion="true"` to be sure that after `7` release your aggregator is ready to collect a fresh group for the same `correlationKey`.